# Orthonormal set of basis functions in $L^2([a,b])$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, orthonormal

I am wondering about the basis functions for $$e_n(x)=\frac{e^{2\pi i n x/L}}{\sqrt(L)}$$ where $L = b - a$ on the domain of $L^2([a,b])$ when doing fourier series. Basically, we must scale it by $L = b - a$ but I am wondering about the case where we need to shift the domain.

For instance, if we consider $L^2([-1,1])$ which has orthonormal basis functions of $$e_n(x) = \frac{e^{2\pi i n x/2}}{\sqrt(2)}$$

But when changing the domain from $[a,b] = [-.5,1.5]$, why is it that we must subtract $.5$ so that the orthonormal basis function becomes $$e_n(x) = \frac{e^{(2\pi i n (x+.5)/2}}{\sqrt(2)}$$

So I'm wondering why is it that we must shift the domain in the second case but not in the first case and to generalize it in a more general context, must we shift the domain if: $\left| a \right| \neq \left| b \right|$ on the domain of $[a,b]$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is periodicity. If you have for example $\sin x$, or $e^{inx}$, it doesn't really matter too much which $2\pi$ length interval you look at it on, it's still got all of the same information. So if we were doing Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi)$ or $[0,2\pi)$ we can use the same functions, since translating them all doesn't change them (since they are periodic). However when we change the *length* of the interval we are doing Fourier series on, we need the basis functions to have period the same length as the interval. Hence $e^{2\pi inx/L}/\sqrt{L}$. The $2\pi/L$ in the exponent changes the period to be $L$, and the $\sqrt{L}$ in the denominator is to normalize the basis, but we don't need to translate since that doesn't change (in any meaningful way) a periodic function (if you translate all functions).

Perhaps an equation will make this more clear.

Let $f$ and $g$ be in $L^2([0,x))$, extend them with period $x$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Now $$\int_0^x f(t)g(t)\,dt = \int_a^{x+a} f(t)g(t)\,dt$$ since $f$ and $g$ are periodic, so the integral will be the same across any interval of length $x$.
Then we can change variables to get 
$$\int_0^x f(t)g(t)\,dt = \int_0^x f(t+a)g(t+a) \,dt$$

Therefore $\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle=\langle f(t+a),g(t+a)\rangle$ so translating the functions doesn't change the bilinear form, or the theory of Fourier series on this interval.

Comment: Interesting, because my prof said that when the domain is $[-.5,1.5]$, then it should be $e_n(x) = \frac{e^{(2\pi i n (x+.5)/2}}{\sqrt(2)}$ but yet a solution on a problem set with the domain $[-1,1]$ is $e_n(x) = \frac{e^{2\pi i n (x)/2}{2}$, so both of these are an orthonormal basis ? In that sense, to confirm, one never needs to translate the domain right ?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are periodic.